# Can I apply for Canada Visit Visa in US when my H-1B is expired but have valid I-797?

Tags: visas, canada, h1b-visas

Can I apply for Canada Visit Visa in US when my H-1B is expired but have valid 
I-797? I intend to visit Canada to apply for H-1B visa.